# I really want to see this question asked in a constructive way and have the same answers, how?

Tags: discussion

This question: [Why do religious people find it hard to accept that you don't need religion to have a good moral code?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14504/why-do-religious-people-find-it-hard-to-accept-that-you-dont-need-religion-to-h)

It is currently closed.

I think the question deserves to be on this site, however, I can't think of a way that it might be asked without creating the same issues that the original closers objected to in the first place. I think the biggest issue was that it assumes the majority of Christians think this way when that is not really so, however, the assumption is quite common among non-Christians. Despite this, I think some of the answers really answer it well.

I asked [this related question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/without-god-is-there-only-evil) and received mixed answers, although the one I selected I think answers it perfectly, however, I came under the same scrutiny and objections, but I suppose not enough to close it and without downvotes or upvotes.

I want to get the closed question back up, either new post or reopened, with whatever made my question stay open. Anybody have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to re-phrase that question in a way that meets site guidelines **and** isn't based on false assumptions, **and** in a way that hasn't already been asked.

The root of the problem with the question is that it is based on the false assumption that "religious people" think that non-religious people can't do good things.  That's utter bunk.  There is nothing within Christianity that says that non-religious people can't do good, or have a "good moral code".

It's possible that people get confused because from a Christian perspective, a good moral code isn't what gets you into Heaven.

Another possible point of confusion is that the Christian perspective is that all good things come from God, that God plants a conscience within us, so even e non-religious person's morality comes from God.

The point is, that the only way you can even ask that question honestly is if you completely misunderstand central doctrines. The best we can do is to try up the misconceptions so that people asking this realize that the question is invalid in and of itself.

As an analogy, the question "Why are apples the size of an automobile in Mobile Alabama?" is a bad question because apples simpl aren't as big as automobiles in Mobile Alabama.  No amount of editing to the question could make it a sensible question.

Comparatively, Christians, religious people, etc. do think that non-religious people can have a "good" moral code.  No amount of rephrasing the question will change the fact that the assumption it's based on is flawed, and therefore the question isn't sensible.

If you take "why" out of the title of the question, it eliminates the issue of being based on a false assumption. But that has already been asked on the site.

- [Is it possible for an atheist to be moral?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3016/is-it-possible-for-an-atheist-to-be-moral)
- [Is morality possible apart from God?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3226/is-morality-possible-apart-from-god)

Comment: We have many questions that have assumptions but the answers clear that up. [You said so yourself that is good](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1518/do-not-assume/1520#1520). Have you had a change of heart or did I misunderstand that post? Does the fact that this assumption is common mean nothing?